# Laravel 5.7: Forgot Password using localhost

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I execute the command

```
php artisan auth
```

I improved it in a bit such as:

```
1) Added username field in registration
2) Login using email or username
3) Added a "Show Password" checkbox in registration
```

The video that I'm watching regarding to login,registration and forgot password instead of using the mailtrap he changed it to log.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log // from smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

It will create a new file in my storage but when I paste the link

```
http://localhost/password/reset/79c928010990374851c949776d95a86a248364df3625c643baaf13f81787b694
```

it gives me an error "Object not found!".

Question: How can I fix this error?

Comment: your `localhost` url is not working correctly, you should include working directory as well, for e.g. `http://localhost/laravel/password/reset/<token>`

Comment: Oh. Now I know my mistake. instead of http://localhost/laravel/password/reset/<token> it should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/<token>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rajender Verma, I realized that instead of localhost/password/reset/token it should be 127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset/token

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script through `php artisan serve` command then the url in the reset password will exist localhost which must be replaced with `127.0.0.1:8000` if there is no port given in the param. If you run the command with `--port="The port you rant to run on"` then replace `8000` port and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the reset password link. Replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1:8000` and paste it in the URL bar.